# google drive php api returns 403

Tags: php, google-chrome

I was able to retrive the images from google drive and put it on web by PHP. One month ago, the same code return 403. Does google changed the policy by not letting us to embed photos from drive directly on website?
thanks

```
<link href="<?= plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) ?>/library/lightbox2-2.11.3/dist/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?= plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) ?>/library/lightbox2-2.11.3/dist/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        // echo 'g1='.date("Y/m/d H:i:s").'<br>';
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);
        $client->setAuthConfig('/home/quantr.foundation/www/credentials.json');
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        $optParams = array(
            // 'pageSize' => 10,
            //'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, mimeType, exportLinks)'
            'fields' => '*',
            'orderBy' => 'createdTime desc'
        );
        $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
        // var_dump($results);

        if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
            echo "No files found.<br>";
        } else {
            foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
                if (strpos($file->getMimeType(), "image") !== false) {
                    $fileId = $file->getId();
                    // echo "<div class='col-md-2 col-sm-6' style='padding: 5px;'>".$file->getWebViewLink()."</div>";
                    echo "
                    <div class='col-6 col-md-2' style='padding: 5px;'>
                        <div style='position: relative;'>
                            <a href='" . $file->getWebContentLink() . "' data-lightbox='image-1' data-title='" . $file->description . "'>
                                <img src='" . $file->getWebContentLink() . "' class='img-fluid' style='border-radius:5px;' />
                            </a>
                            <div style='font-size:10px; position: absolute; width: 100%; bottom: 0px; background-color: #00000088; color: white; padding: 2px;'>".$file->description."</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
                }
            }
        }
        // echo 'g2='.date("Y/m/d H:i:s").'<br>';
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Error 403 means that the code tries to open a resource that it's not allowed to access.